# plot function in R producing legend without legend() being called

Tags: r, plot, legend, legend-properties

I'm trying to produce a cumulative incidence plot for a competing hazards survival analysis using plot() in R. For some reason, the plot that is produced has a legend that I have not called. The legend is intersecting with the lines on my graph and I can't figure out how to get rid of it. Please help!

My code is as follows:

```
CompRisk2 <- cuminc(ftime=ADI$time_DeathTxCensor, fstatus=ADI$status, group=ADI$natADI_quart)
cols <- c("darkorange","coral1","firebrick1","firebrick4","lightskyblue","darkturquoise","dodgerblue","dodgerblue4")
par(bg="white")
plot(CompRisk2,
     col=cols,
     xlab="Years",
     ylab="Probability of Mortality or Transplant",
     xlim=c(0,10),
     ylim=c(0,0.6))
```

Which produces the following plot:
[image]

I tried adding the following code to move the legend out of the frame, but I got an error:

```
legend(0,5, legend=c(11,21,31,41,12,22,32,42),
col=c("darkorange","coral1","firebrick1","firebrick4","lightskyblue","darkturquoise","dodgerblue","dodgerblue4"),
lty=1:2, cex=0.8, text.font=4, box.lty=0)
```

Error: *Error in title(...) : invalid graphics parameter*

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the ellipsis arguments are intended for the `legend` call inside `plot.cuminc`. The code offered in Ben's answer suggests that there might be a `wh` argument that determines the location of the legend. It is not named within the parameters as "x" in the code he offered, but is rather given as a positionally-defined argument. If you look at the `plot.cuminc` function you do in fact find that `wh` is documented.

I cannot test this because you have not offered us access to the `ADI`-object but my suggestion would be to try:

```
opar <- par(xpd=TRUE) # xpd lets graphics be placed 'outside'
plot(CompRisk2,
     col=cols, wh=c(-.5, 7), 
     xlab="Years",
     ylab="Probability of Mortality or Transplant",
     xlim=c(0,10),
     ylim=c(0,0.6))
 par(opar)  # restores original graphics parameters
```

It's always a bit risky to put out a code chunk without testing, but I'm happy to report that I did find a suitable test and it seems to work reasonably as predicted. Using the code below on the object in the SO question  [prior question about using the gg-packages for cmprsk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64186565/customizing-a-competing-risks-plot-in-r-with-package-cmprsk):

```
library(cmprsk)
# some simulated data to get started
comp.risk.data <- data.frame("tfs.days" = rweibull(n = 100, shape = 1, scale = 1)*100,
                             "status.tfs" = c(sample(c(0,1,1,1,1,2), size=50, replace=T)),
                             "Typing" = sample(c("A","B","C","D"), size=50, replace=T))

# fitting a competing risks model
CR <- cuminc(ftime = comp.risk.data$tfs.days, 
             fstatus = comp.risk.data$status.tfs, 
             cencode = 0,
             group = comp.risk.data$Typing)

opar <- par(xpd=TRUE) # xpd lets graphics be placed 'outside'
plot(CR,
      wh=c(-15, 1.1),  # obviously different than the OP's coordinates
     xlab="Years",
     ylab="Probability of Mortality or Transplant",
     xlim=c(0,400),
     ylim=c(0,1))
par(opar)   # restores graphics parameters
```

I get the legend to move up and leftward from its original position.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `cuminc` function from the `cmprsk` package. This produces an object of class `cuminc`, which has an S3 plot method. `?plot.cuminc` shows you the documentation and typing `plot.cuminc` shows you the code.

There is some slightly obscure code that suggests a workaround:

```r
 u <- list(...)
    if (length(u) > 0) {
        i <- pmatch(names(u), names(formals(legend)), 0)
        do.call("legend", c(list(x = wh[1], y = wh[2], legend = curvlab, 
            col = color, lty = lty, lwd = lwd, bty = "n", bg = -999999), 
            u[i > 0]))
    }
```

This says that any additional arguments passed in `...` *whose names match the names of arguments to `legend`* will be passed to `legend()`. `legend()` has a `plot` argument:

> plot: logical.  If ‘FALSE’, nothing is plotted but the sizes are  returned.

So it looks like adding `plot=FALSE` to your `plot()` command will work.

In principle you could try looking at the other arguments to `legend()` and see if any of them will adjust the legend position/size as you want. Unfortunately the `x` argument to legend (which would determine the horizontal position) is masked by the first argument to `plot.cuminc`.

Comment: This is an extremely rare instance where you seem to have missed the obvious. I mention only because you are typically the "smartest kid on the block" w.r.t. regression packages, and I did find the answer useful if a bit incomplete. I think you were staring at the answer.